# What changes to a .zshrc file could cause every terminal one opens to output: '@home/.zshrc:1: command not found: xyz'?

Tags: shell, zsh, gnome-terminal, oh-my-zsh, rxvt

('xyz' can be as far as I know, anything that is on my first line of .zshrc. Even an empty line as a first line of .zshrc returns the same output upon opening a terminal but ending with whitespace. I also tried `pwd` thinking of all instances of terminal input that could be found somewhere and what I assume is one of the most universal commands, but it too can not be found.)

I'm certain the issue has arisen strictly from changes in my .zshrc file because the problem occurred after hours of tweaking it/closing & opening terminals to test fixes to a previous issue involving aliases conflicting between .zshrc and oh-my-zsh (Namely, I was unaware oh-my-zsh added a line to source somefile that somehow takes precedence over my custom aliases on .zshrc. See link: [Why doesn't 'sourcing' my .zshrc file change my aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497834/87522)).

Potentially relevent/generally helpful info:

-Problem occurs in both gnome-terminal(preferred and used almost exclusively) and urxvt(backup).
-Other than this consistent 1st hiccup, everything else works perfectly fine. Even all my aliases and oh-my-zsh schemes function properly.

--`fortune -o` was my initial first line before I began experimenting to find solutions. (it also returned `command not found: fortune`)

--A big indicator of what I potentially messed up probably involves oh-my-zsh in someway because my last attempt to fix the problem mentioned in the link above, was to add

`source $home/.zshrc`

directly below the line containing `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

The idea behind this was my thinking that `source`ing my custom .zshrc file would cause the aliases within that file to take precedence over whatever aliases are being determined by the oh-my-zsh file which I don't much know about/understand/how it got there to begin with. After saving the file, closing the terminal and opening a new one up to test the alias changes, a very confusing bug occured. The terminal opened up normally and the color scheme and everything else about it aesthetically was accurate, but it was looping random fortunes at a fairly rapid pace in an unending loop. No common keybindings worked to stop it(Ctrl+C, Ctrl+D, Esc, Enter, 'Q'). So I had to close it with a gnome keybinding. The error persisted on urxvt in the exact same manner. Removing the `source $home/.zshrc` line solved my looping fortune issue but caused my current conundrum

Comment: I'm wondering if you can get closer to finding out what's wrong by starting zsh with -v (i.e. open any terminal with any shell, and in there start `zsh -v`). This should tell you what gets executed and what scripts get sourced from other scripts (will probably be very much output). I'm wondering if your `zshrc` gets sourced a second time, on top of the regular call by `zsh`).

Comment: Its a pretty excessive amount of output that I can't make much sense of. Should I throw it in a pastebin or something?

Comment: the "big indicator" is probably a red herring. by calling `source $HOME/.zshrc` from within `.zshrc` you just created an infinite loop of a script calling itself.

Comment: hm, i was afraid the output could be too big to handle. and someone other than you might even have more problem as they're unfamiliar with what you have in your scripts (which you could recognize). Can you try going towards a minimum working example? i.e. remove things from your .zshrc (make a backup before, or even put it in version control to go through your steps) until the error disappears? I suspect once you exclude oh-my-zsh.sh the -v output might even become readable, and we'll know if the problem is on your side / on the oh-my-zsh side / a combination of both.

Comment: Excluding oh-my-zsh.sh didn't affect the output at all from what I can make out. The output from zsh -v seems to be a list of every command possible followed by my usual .zshrc file

Comment: "every command possible followed by my usual .zshrc file" okay, so what is the last thing before your zshrc? since apparently the beginning of your zshrc is command-not-found'ed something that happens before tries to run it (or expects a command). looking at [this post](https://medium.com/@rajsek/zsh-bash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc-e30045652f2e), could there be something buggy in your .zprofile or .zshenv (or worse, in /etc/zsh*)

Comment: After commenting out the line that sources oh-my-zsh in my .zshrc and running `zsh -v 2>&1 | tee zsh-v-output.txt`

the first 2 lines of the output file are `zstyle :compinstall filename '$home/.zshrc'

$home/.zshrc:1: command not found: <feff>zstyle`
Where `<feff>` seems to be one character somehow?

Comment: I also don't have a .zprofile or a .zshenv file anywhere on my system, but I don't recall ever having those files to begin with. Is that really an issue?

Comment: "what is the last thing before your zshrc?" I don't really know how to answer this because the entire output file seems to be nothing but the mere expansion of my .zshrc. When I said 'every command possible' I meant that it's roughly 2000 lines of commands in quotes. But these lines seem to just be some type of expansion of the `autoload -Uz compinit` line which is the 3rd line of my .zshrc file. That is the entirety of my `zsh -v` output.

Comment: a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark probably should remove those from the file, as they are not recommended for UTF-8

Comment: The byte order Mark only shows up in the out put of `zsh -v`. I don't see it anywhere in my .zshrc. Although I also don't understand what it really is, so I'm not entirely sure how to search for it with a vim 'find' function either.

Comment: When experiencing the unending fortune loop, I was struggling to find a way to edit my .zshrc because I've only ever used vim, which wasn't an option because every terminal was just looping fortunes. So I commented out the `source $home/.zshrc` line using libreoffice. Could that explain why there's some invisible BOM that vim doesn't display when I look at .zshrc?

Answer (score 0):

The entirety of this issue hinged on 2 complications. The first was my bonehead mistake of thinking I could have a script `source` itself. Perhaps this is possible in other contexts, but in my specific case it caused an infinite loop of my .zshrc calling itself. The second complication arose from a poor attempt to resolve the first issue: using libreoffice to edit a system configuration file. My infinte script call made all terminals unusable and with no other gui text editors available, I thought libreoffice would be fine for a single line change edit. When saving any textfile, it appears that libreoffice, as of this date, will prepend textfiles with a Byte Order Mark(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). I don't know much about them at all, but I can say for certain that the default vim editor will not display them in any noticeable way without vim commands.

You can remove the aforementioned BOMs in vim, though.
`:set bomb?` will output `bomb` if the current file does indeed have a BOM. Conversely, `nobomb` will be returned if none are present.

And intuitively enough, you can have vim remove this with `:set nobomb`

Do remember to save the file afterward, though. Otherwise, no change will occur.